# How can I delete an image from chat that takes up massive amount of screen space?

Tags: support, chat

How can I delete an image from chat that takes up massive amount of screen space?

[image]

Comment: If you're a room owner, you can move the message to another room you own. Only moderators can delete messages.

Comment: You can't without userscripts atm. I'd certainly support a feature request to make oneboxes/images/gifs collapsible in chat.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309659/460139 (requests room owners to be able to delete messages)

Comment: [Related on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161278/369403) with userscript to collapse chat messages

Comment: If it's not sent by you, then only a room owner can move it or a moderator can delete it.

Comment: A usermade chat theme I use by @rlemon ([sauce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/so-dark-chat-%20/bbkjccfnenmgidehjhaabamobpbaaghh)) has a built in collapse feature that I use for moments like that. Otherwise the user has to un-onebox it, or an RO needs to move the message out of the chat

Comment: Adblockers are a wonderful thing.  Right-click, block.  Done!

Comment: @Stijn You can move messages to _**any room that you have access**_ if you are a room owner in the room the message is in.

Comment: @smileycreations15 thanks for the correction. I've never tried it myself, just got the info from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124510/167646).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it:

1. Click on the <kbd>room</kbd> link at the sidebar and select <kbd>Move messages</kbd>.
2. Then select the message to move (select more than one with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>).
3. Then click <kbd>Relocate</kbd>.
4. Then to find a bin/trash room to move the message in, type one of the terms below into the text input to find a bin room. (or type the room that you want to move it in)

   - bin
   - trash
   - trash bin
5. Click on the <kbd>choose</kbd> button on the room and done.